# How to set The Home Page has default Page After User Successfully Register

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9, nsuserdefaults

I am successfully getting the results from the server.
is registration is success i want to set the homepage as default.

for this code I am getting the response like:

```
  Data = {"response":"yes","success":"This mobile registered successfully"}
```

if response is yes I want to redirect to my home view controller.

When the registration is success when user click on my app automatically my homepage should be open.

Thank you.

Comment: By setting the rootViewController you can solve your problem

Comment: @Navin What is yopur project Navigation hirarchy?

Comment: first page (reg)view controller then controller move to 1 tabview controller.it contains 5 tabs.  when user successfully register my app page will be 1st tab view controller .  my reg page contains 1.textfield and 1 button for moving to tab view controller.@vvk Aghera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you got Succesfully Response set there

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"login"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

then set in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"login"] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) 
{
  CallViewController *loginController=[[UIStoryboard  storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"]; 
  UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationControlleralloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];

  [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
  self.window.rootViewController=navController;
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: in my code there is no login key..@ishu hingu     so i need to set the key value for "dataTask"

Comment: i am setting that identifier name as RegisterViewController @ishu hingu    Help Me ......

Comment: i think you no set RegisterViewController identity in viewcontroller